# Mysql format date to insert to table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to format and insert the date to mysql table which is type of datetime, I am doing this from php.

Here is the statement

```
$timestamp ="22-11-2015+00:00:00";
$mysqltime = date ("d-m-Y H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

But when I insert to table the date is wrong, it showing `31-12-1969 19:00:22`

What could be the issue?

Comment: You dont have time in that date,it`s the timezone offset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
$timestamp ="22-11-2015+00:00:00";
$mysqltime = date ("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($timestamp));
```

because `date` is expecting it's second parameter to be a number, specifically the number of seconds since midnight January 1st, 1970.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, now the qurey looks ok `insert into TABLE values('imo','remote','cam1','22-11-2015 00:00:00','NULL','NULL','RECOG','test.jpg')` , but when I look on the table I can see the datetime column `0000-00-00 00:00:00` through phpmyadmin

Comment: Running the code above, I get `01-01-1970 01:00:00`. Why is that?

Comment: @HasseBjörk  Because it's not converting the date correctly, if your date format is not `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` you should use the [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function instead of `strtotime` and state the actual format you're using

Answer (score 1):

I think the corret format would be:

```
$mysqltime = date_format ($timestamp,"d-m-Y H:i:s");
```

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 1):

The date function expects an integer timestamp for the second argument.

This MSQL insert statement would work fine:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (birthday) ('2015-11-22 00:00:00')
```

If you're using a database class in PHP and the function you're calling is using a PHP date object, then you'd have to construct the PHP date object using the date() function.

Or if you want to use PHP code to reformat the date in PHP before sending the string to the database to be inserted, then I think you'd use strtodate to get a PHP date object, and then date()

```
$phpdate = strtodate('d-m-Y H:i:s', '22-11-2015 00:00:00')
$dateformysql = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate)
databaseclass.dotheinsert($mysqldate)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be working, but did not work for me!

```
$timestamp ="22-11-2015+00:00:00";
$mysqltime = date ("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($timestamp));
```

I believe it is because my national standard format (LC_TIME) is "Y-m-d" rather then "d-m-Y". However this works perfectly:

```
$timestamp ="22-11-2015+00:00:00";
// The '+' sign needs to be escaped!!
$time = date_create_from_format( "d-m-Y\+H:i:s", $timestamp);
$mysqltime = $time->format( 'd-m-Y H:i:s' );
```

On the other hand, [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) use the date format "YYYY-MM-DD" as a standard. The correct format string should be:

```
$mysqltime = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($timestamp));
// or second option
$mysqltime = $time->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```